# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que estos for impriman estos datos de la forma que les mostraré?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

¿Cómo están? Soy nueva en *c++* esta pregunta ya la había echo pero quise volverla hacer porque no se logró entender bien, estoy aprendiendo todo desde el inicio así que tal vez a algunos se les haga una pregunta muy fácil u obvia pero yo estoy comenzando.

Estoy haciendo un programa sencillo pero no entiendo por qué estos *for* me solicitan los datos 8 veces cuando deberían hacerlo solo 2 veces por cada *for*, en total 4 veces. ¿Me explicarían por qué sucede esto?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int acumulador1, acumulador2;
     acumulador1=0;
     acumulador2=0;

     for(int i=1; i<=2;i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=2;j++){

           int primernumero,segundonumero;

           cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :"<<i<<endl;
           cin>>primernumero;
           cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :"<<j<<endl;
           cin>>segundonumero;

           acumulador1 = acumulador1+primernumero;
           acumulador2 = acumulador2+segundonumero;
        }

    }

    cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 1 es :"<<acumulador1<<endl;
    cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 2 es :"<<acumulador2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

El código debería hacer lo siguiente:

> PRIMEROS DOS NUMEROS
>
> Ingrese el primer numero :" 3
>
> Ingrese el segundo numero :" 2
>
> SEGUNDOS DOS NUMEROS
>
> Ingrese el primer numero :" 3
>
> Ingrese el segundo numero :" 2
>
> El resultado del acumulador 1 es : 6
>
> El resultado del acumulador 2 es : 4

Esto es lo que debería hacer el programa pero no entiendo como hacerlo me podrían ayudar le sigo dando vueltas pero no entiendo como pedir solo 4 veces los datos 2 por cada *for*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lógica es correcta, el código dentro del `for` se ejecuta 4 veces, pero se piden dos veces los datos, por eso se ve como si se ejecutara 8 veces.

```
// primera vez
Ingrese el primer numero :1
1
Ingrese el segundo numero :1
1
// segunda vez
Ingrese el primer numero :1
1
Ingrese el segundo numero :2
1
// tercera vez
Ingrese el primer numero :2
1
Ingrese el segundo numero :1
1
// cuarta vez
Ingrese el primer numero :2
1
Ingrese el segundo numero :2
1
El resultado del acumulador 1 es :4
El resultado del acumulador 2 es :4
```

Si buscas que se vea como tu solución solo es necesario reducir los limites de ambos for, aunque lo optimo seria tener un solo for; ejemplos:

```cpp
for( int i = 1; i<= 2; i++) {

    int primernumero,segundonumero;

    cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :";
    cin>>primernumero;
    cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :";
    cin>>segundonumero;

    acumulador1 = acumulador1+primernumero;
    acumulador2 = acumulador2+segundonumero;
}

// o bien

for( int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

    for( int j = 1; j<= 1; j++) {

        int primernumero,segundonumero;

        cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :"<<i<<endl;
        cin>>primernumero;
        cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :"<<j<<endl;
        cin>>segundonumero;

        acumulador1 = acumulador1+primernumero;
        acumulador2 = acumulador2+segundonumero;
    }

}
```

Comment: jjeje muchas gracias @denso, no me di cuenta que con un solo for ya se podia hacer gracias por tu ayuda, talves sea muy facil para ti pero como yo apenas estoy aprendiendo c++

Comment: No te preocupes @EstherPorta todos iniciamos sin saber nada, asi que es un gusto que se haya resuleto tu duda.